# Running multiple test cases in jbehave

Tags: jbehave

I am new to jbehave. I need to call jbehave from junit.

How can I run multiple test cases in jbehave.

Answer (score 0):

You can write multiple stories by this:

```
@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    return new StoryFinder()
            .findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass).getFile(), asList("**/*.story"), null);
}
```

You also can specify which stories to run. For example this will run all purchasing stories:

```
 ...asList("**/purchasing-*.story"), null)
```

Source: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/developing-stories.html#configuring